# Brightness function keys not working in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, dell, brightness

I recently updated the BIOS (1.30.0) of my Dell Latitude 5480 laptop running with Ubuntu 22.04.
Now the screen is darker (I can see the change while booting) and even `xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 1` doesn't fix the problem.
It turns out that now all the function keys work except for the brighness ones.
So here are the solutions I've tried so far:

**1:**

`sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

```
Section "Device"   
        Identifier  "card0"   
        Driver      "intel"   
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"   
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"   
EndSection
```

**2:**

`sudo vim /etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

`sudo update-grub`

**3:**

`sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/framework-als-blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist hid_sensor_hub
```

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

None of these have worked for me.
Any idea ?